# Unable to disable extensions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, multilingual-app-toolkit

I am unable to disable/remove some extensions in Visual Studio 2015, including extensions like the "Multilingual App Toolkit" and "MySQL for Visual Studio" that I have installed myself. In several cases, both the `Disable` and `Uninstall` buttons are grayed out in the Extensions and Updates manager.

[image: Visual Studio Extensions - showing greyed out disable and uninstall options]

I've tried starting VS as administrator, and also launching VS in safe mode (using `devenv.exe /safemode`).

Why is it not possible to disable some extensions, and what is the correct way to safely disable them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manage extensions from Visual Studio only if they use standard .vsix  installer. If they use other installer like .msi you typically use Control Panel - Programs and Features to uninstall them.

Answer (score 3):

Windows *Control Panel -> Programs and Features* can uninstall most of those addons.

For anything else, there is an awesome simple utility: [Total-Uninstaller](https://github.com/tsasioglu/Total-Uninstaller). It can uninstall virtually anything, including hidden stuff.

Warning: uninstalling too much can make Visual Studio crashing / unusable and can even damage Windows installation. Make sure to back up important info before proceeding.